# Adding text, images, pictures and barcodes to a PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Maybe I am making this harder than it is, but I am having a heck of time getting everything to layout together, or even appear on my pdf.

In my code, CreatePdf is called a single time for creation of a badge front, then a single time for the badge back.  All the object parts of the pdf are stored in a database, and are then looped through in this method.

The original method only used the 'graph' object to create the pdf, with barcodes generated with the iText CreateDrawingImage which worked great...EXCEPT all the barcodes were quite blurry.  To combat this, the method was changed to use both the graph object and the iText Image, using CreateImageWithBarcode.

The problem is, that no matter what I do with iText image, it does not layout where I want it to on the pdf.  The barcode is supposed to be at the bottom of the badge, but with the iText image, the barcode moves itself to the top of the pdf, over the top of the graph items.

When I changed all the different item types to all use iText image, nothing laid out correctly, or even showed on the pdf.

I would prefer to use the graph to lay it all out, but the result of iText CreateDrawingImage is unusable.  Below in the switch statement, 'C128', 'Code39' and 'I25' are the items I am having trouble with.  If anybody knows how I can get around these issues to layout a clean badge, it would be MUCH appreciated.  If there is a clean way of making CreateDrawingImage create a crisp barcode, it would be preferred.

Developing this in VS 2019 C#, using iTextSharp 5.5.13.1

```
    private byte[] CreatePDF(BadgeLayoutDTO badgeLayout, Document doc, PdfContentByte cb)
    {
        if (badgeLayout == null)
            return null;

        var width = Convert.ToInt32(badgeLayout.Width);
        var height = Convert.ToInt32(badgeLayout.Height);

        var offset = -50;

        // Create the new bitmap
        using (Image image = new Bitmap(width, height))
        {
            var graph = Graphics.FromImage(image);

            // Draw a border around the badge if specified
            if (badgeLayout.Outline > 0)
            {
                var pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, badgeLayout.Outline);
                graph.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
            }

            foreach (var field in badgeLayout.BdgFieldList.OrderBy(x => x.FldPosition.FldTop))
            {
                var x = Convert.ToInt32(field.FldPosition.FldLeft * RatioHorz + badgeLayout.OffsetHorz / 2);
                var y = Convert.ToInt32(field.FldPosition.FldTop * RatioVert + badgeLayout.OffsetVert / 2);
                var w = Convert.ToInt32((field.FldPosition.FldRight - field.FldPosition.FldLeft) * RatioHorz);
                var h = Convert.ToInt32((field.FldPosition.FldBottom - field.FldPosition.FldTop) * RatioVert);

                switch (field.FldType)
                {
                    case "ShadedRoundRectangle":
                    case "RoundRect":
                    {
                        const float xradius = 5;
                        const float yradius = 5;
                        var brush = new SolidBrush(AccessToHex(field.FldColor.BkColor)); // Fill Color
                        var pen = new Pen(AccessToHex(field.FldColor.ForeColor),
                            field.FldPosition.FldSize + 3); // Border color
                        var rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

                        using (pen)
                        {
                            var path = MakeRoundedRect(rect, xradius, yradius, true, true, true, true);
                            graph.FillPath(brush, path);
                            graph.DrawPath(pen, path);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    case "ShadeRect":
                    {
                        var brush = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Cross, AccessToHex(field.FldColor.BkColor - 100),
                            AccessToHex(field.FldColor.BkColor));
                        var pen = new Pen(AccessToHex(field.FldColor.ForeColor),
                            field.FldPosition.FldSize + 3); // Border color
                        var rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
                        graph.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                        graph.FillRectangle(brush, rect);

                        break;
                    }
                    case "Rectangle":
                    {
                        var brush = new SolidBrush(AccessToHex(field.FldColor.BkColor));
                        var pen = new Pen(AccessToHex(field.FldColor.ForeColor),
                            field.FldPosition.FldSize + 3); // Border color
                        var rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
                        graph.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                        graph.FillRectangle(brush, rect);

                        break;
                    }
                    case "Ellipse":
                    {
                        var brush = new SolidBrush(AccessToHex(field.FldColor.BkColor));
                        var pen = new Pen(AccessToHex(field.FldColor.ForeColor),
                            field.FldPosition.FldSize + 3); // Border color
                        var rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
                        graph.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);
                        graph.FillEllipse(brush, rect);

                        break;
                    }
                    case "ShadedEllipse":
                    {
                        var brush = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Cross, AccessToHex(field.FldColor.BkColor - 100),
                            AccessToHex(field.FldColor.BkColor));
                        var pen = new Pen(AccessToHex(field.FldColor.ForeColor),
                            field.FldPosition.FldSize + 3); // Border color
                        var rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
                        graph.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);
                        graph.FillEllipse(brush, rect);

                        break;
                    }
                    case "Image":
                    {
                        if (field.FldData?.FldDataValue == null)
                            continue;

                            var dbimage = _filePicture.Get(field.FldData.FldDataValue.ToString(), 36);

                            //var imageJ = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(dbimage.FileImage);
                            //imageJ.SetAbsolutePosition(x, y + offset);

                            //var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
                            //imageJ.ScaleToFit(rect);

                            //doc.Add(imageJ);

                            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(dbimage.FileImage))
                            {
                                var newImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

                                // Resize image to proper aspect ratio
                                var aspect = ResizeKeepAspect(newImage.Size, w, h);
                                var aspectImage = ResizeImage(newImage, new Size(aspect.Width, aspect.Height));

                                // Create Point for upper-left corner of image.
                                var ulCorner = new Point(x, y);

                                // Draw image to screen.
                                graph.DrawImage(aspectImage, ulCorner);
                            }

                            break;
                    }
                    case "QRCode":
                    {
                        if (field.FldData?.FldDataValue == null)
                            continue;

                        QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
                        QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(field.FldData?.FldDataValue.ToString(), QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
                        QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
                        Bitmap dbImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
                        var aspect = ResizeKeepAspect(dbImage.Size, w, h);
                        var aspectImage = ResizeBadgeImage(dbImage, new Size(aspect.Width, aspect.Height));
                        using (var ms2 = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                aspectImage.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                                var signatureImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ms2.ToArray());
                                signatureImage.SetAbsolutePosition(x, y + offset - 100);
                                doc.Add(signatureImage);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(e);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case "C128":
                    {
                        if (field.FldData?.FldDataValue == null)
                            continue;

                        var dbImage = (new Barcode128()
                        {
                            Code = field.FldData?.FldDataValue.ToString()
                        });

                        iTextSharp.text.Image image128 = dbImage.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, BaseColor.WHITE);
                        image128.SetAbsolutePosition(x, y + offset);
                        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
                        image128.ScaleToFit(rect);
                        doc.Add(image128);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "Code39":
                    {
                        if (field.FldData?.FldDataValue == null)
                            continue;

                        var dbImage = (new Barcode39
                        {
                            Code = field.FldData?.FldDataValue.ToString()
                        });

                        iTextSharp.text.Image image128 = dbImage.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, BaseColor.WHITE);
                        image128.SetAbsolutePosition(x, y + offset);
                        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
                        image128.ScaleToFit(rect);

                        doc.Add(image128);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "I25":
                    {
                        if (field.FldData?.FldDataValue == null)
                            continue;

                        var dbImage = (new BarcodeInter25()
                        {
                            Code = field.FldData?.FldDataValue.ToString()
                        });

                        iTextSharp.text.Image image128 = dbImage.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, BaseColor.WHITE);
                        image128.SetAbsolutePosition(x, y + offset);

                        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
                        image128.ScaleToFit(rect);

                        doc.Add(image128);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "Picture":
                    {
                        if (field.FldData?.FldDataValue == null)
                            continue;

                        var dbimage = _filePicture.Get(field.FldData.FldDataValue.ToString(), 48);

                        //var imageJ = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(dbimage.FileImage);
                        //imageJ.SetAbsolutePosition(x, y + offset);

                        //var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
                        //imageJ.ScaleToFit(rect);

                        //doc.Add(imageJ);
                        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(dbimage.FileImage))
                        {
                            var newImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

                            // Resize image to proper aspect ratio
                            var aspect = ResizeKeepAspect(newImage.Size, w, h);
                            var aspectImage = ResizeImage(newImage, new Size(aspect.Width, aspect.Height));

                            //var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);

                            // Create Point for upper-left corner of image.
                            var ulCorner = new Point(x, y);

                            // Draw image to screen.
                            graph.DrawImage(aspectImage, ulCorner);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    case "Signature":
                    {
                        if (field.FldData?.FldDataValue == null)
                            continue;

                        var dbimage = _filePicture.Get(field.FldData.FldDataValue.ToString(), 36);

                        if (dbimage == null) continue;

                            //iTextSharp.text.Image imageJ = new Jpeg(dbimage.FileImage);
                            //imageJ.SetAbsolutePosition(x, y + offset);

                            //var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
                            //imageJ.ScaleToFit(rect);

                            //doc.Add(imageJ);

                        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(dbimage.FileImage))
                        {
                            var newImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

                            // Resize image to proper aspect ratio
                            var aspect = ResizeKeepAspect(newImage.Size, w, h);
                            var aspectImage = ResizeImage(newImage, new Size(aspect.Width, aspect.Height));

                            // Create Point for upper-left corner of image.
                            var ulCorner = new Point(x, y);

                            // Draw image to screen.
                            graph.DrawImage(aspectImage, ulCorner);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    case "TextCenter":
                    case "TextLeft":
                    case "TextRight":
                    {
                            var text = GetText(field);

                            // Assume here that screen DPI is 96...
                            // If DPI is different, rendering issues might occur...
                            // Badge designer in Desktop assumes 300 DPI
                            var fontSizeDpiRatioFix = 300 / 96; //HACK
                            var fontSize = -field.FldPosition.FldSize * fontSizeDpiRatioFix * 1.03;
                            Font font;
                            try
                            {
                                font = FindFont(graph, text, new Size(w, h),
                                    new Font(new FontFamily(field.FldFont.FontName), (float)fontSize,
                                        GetFontParam(field.FldFont.FontParms)));
                            }
                            catch (Exception exc)
                            {
                                font = System.Drawing.SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
                            }

                            //Create rectangles
                            var rect1 = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

                            //Construct string format and alignment
                            var strFormat1 = new StringFormat
                            {
                                Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                                LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                                Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
                            };

                            // Draw GDI+ objects
                            graph.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Transparent), rect1);
                            graph.DrawString(text, font,
                                new SolidBrush(AccessToHex(field.FldColor.ForeColor)), rect1, strFormat1);

                            //Disposes of objects
                            font.Dispose();

                            break;
                        }
                }
            }

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not add a few line breaks to the post to make it __readable__?

Comment: Have you considered that the coordinate systems on the bitmap image and in the pdf page may differ a lot? Bitmap image APIs usually positions the origin (0,0) at the *top* left and has increasing **y** coordinates *downwards*. PDFs on the other hand can have the origin anywhere (often in the *lower* left corner) and have increasing **y** coordinates *upwards*. Bitmap image APIs usually position objects by their *top* left corner, pdfs by their *bottom* left one. Furthermore, you have to consider the transformation you use when later adding the bitmap to the pdf.

Comment: Thus, you have to transform your coordinates considerably where switching from adding-to-bitmap to adding-to-pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of continuing the battle with iTextSharp barcodes, I instead installed IronBarCodes from Nugget, and was quickly able to get a crisp, clean barcode with only a couple lines of code.  The resulting barcode has the ability to export as a Bitmap, allowing me to use the Graphic layout that the rest of the pdf is using.  Problem solved.

Solution snippet:

```
                    case "C128":
                    {
                        if (field.FldData?.FldDataValue == null)
                            continue;

                        var myBarCode = BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode(field.FldData?.FldDataValue.ToString(), BarcodeEncoding.Code128)
                            .ResizeTo(w,h).ToBitmap();

                        // Create Point for upper-left corner of image.
                        var ulCorner = new Point(x, y);

                        // Draw image to screen.
                        graph.DrawImage(myBarCode, ulCorner);
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: ironbarcode also works for me for QR and barcode generation. https://www.nuget.org/packages/barcode